# Is there a way to verify feature and promo images are OK for publishing Android app on Google play (via developers console)

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way I can verify beforehand (before actually uploading the APK) on Google play developer console that the images - promo images, feature images, screenshots conform to their specification (no alpha, no bleed, 32 bit png or jpeg etc). I have images being created by a 3rd party and I wanted to make sure Google play  will accept it when the times comes to upload my app.

Currently it wouldn't let me upload just the images unless I upload the .apk file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an android apk, sign it while releasing. (Hello World project provided by the Android SDK)
2. Upload it in the console and test your images.
3. Delete afterwards.